# Kendo scheduler month View double click function

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I disabled the built-in pop up event. Now I want to implement a double click function on each cell of the month view.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to associate the event with k-event class of an scheduler.

```
$("#scheduler").on("dblclick", '.k-event', function (e) {
  var scheduler = $("#scheduler").getKendoScheduler();
  var element = $(e.target).is(".k-event") ? $(e.target) : $(e.target).closest(".k-event"); 

  var event = scheduler.occurrenceByUid(element.data("uid"));
  alert("Start Date : " + event.start + ", End Date: " + event.end);
});
```

[Demo Link](http://dojo.telerik.com/IXuMI)

Comment: I have already seen this before. All that I need is 
            $("#scheduler").on("dblclick", function (e) {
                       //Do something here
        });

I still mark yours as the right answer, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event handler to the `add` event of the scheduler in the scheduler options like this:

```
add: (e) => {
    // Place your code here.
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

or in case you would rather not use arrow function:

```
add: function(e) {
    // Place your code here.
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Calling `e.preventDefault()` will disable the built-in "add" event handling which is showing the popup window. You mentioned you already disabled it but this is a good way to do it if you did it in another way.

`e` will contain the slot's start and end time as well as the resource details, if you use resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me.

```
 edit: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); //prevent popup editing
                var dataSource = this.dataSource;
                var event = e.event;
                if (event.isNew()) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        //dataSource.add(event);
                        editEvent(event); // your own function to call
                    });
                }
                else {

                }
            }
```

Comment: He wants the function to run when double-clicking a cell, not an event. That is why the `add:` event is the right choice :)